# Read all rows at once

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I am trying to read all the rows in an SQLite table and display them all at once in a `ListView`. This is how I read them line by line:

```
//---get all titles---
db.open();
Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
String text = "";
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    do {          
        DisplayTitle(c, text);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
db.close();

public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c, String text){
      ListView.setText("id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "ISBN: " + c.getString(1) 
    + "\n" + "TITLE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" + "PUBLISHER:  " + c.getString(3));
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you read **any** tutorials on `ListView` and adapters? [Here's one](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). You might also want to look at [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). Write a class that extends it if you want to show custom data.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a Custom CursorAdapter. Check out this tutorial:

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/